# What am I thinking wrong about field theory?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $\gamma=\frac{1-i}{\sqrt2}$, $\beta=2^\frac{1}{4}$
My goal is to find a nonzero $a\in\mathbb{Q}$ such that $\mathbb{Q}(\beta +a\gamma)\neq\mathbb{Q}(\beta,\gamma)$

But I expect that such $a$ will not exist.
Because, The following holds.

$\mathbb{Q}(\beta +a\gamma)$
$=\mathbb{Q}(\frac{\beta}{\gamma}+a)$
$=\mathbb{Q}(\frac{\beta}{\gamma})$
Since $a$ is rational.

What do you think? My professor claims the existence of this.

Comment: Are you sure that $\mathbb{Q}(\beta +a\gamma)=\mathbb{Q}(\frac{\beta}{\gamma}+a)$?

Comment: @lhf If Not, Why?

Comment: @Edgar.W If $P$ is a polynomial with rational coefficients then $P(\beta +a\gamma)=\gamma^n P(\frac{\beta}{\gamma}+a)$ where $n$ is thde degree of the polynomial. When you say that the two fields are equal you are assuming that $\gamma^n \in \mathbb Q$.

Comment: If $P, Q \in \mathbb{Q}[X]$ irreducible, $P(\beta) = Q(\gamma) = 0$  then $\mathbb{Q}(\beta+\alpha\gamma) \ne \mathbb{Q}(\beta,\gamma) $ iff $\alpha= \frac{\beta-\beta'}{\gamma-\gamma'}$ where $\beta',\gamma'$ are other roots of $P,Q$ (see [this proof](http://www.math.cornell.edu/~kbrown/6310/primitive.pdf))

Comment: @user1952009 This would seem to imply that there is no such $a\in\mathbb{Q}$, as this ratio will always be $\sqrt[4]{2}$ times a nonzero element of $\mathbb{Q}(i,\sqrt{2})$.

Answer (score 5):

$\mathbb{Q}(\frac{\beta}{\gamma}+a)=\mathbb{Q}(\frac{\beta}{\gamma})$ is true but $\mathbb{Q}(\beta +a\gamma)=\mathbb{Q}(\frac{\beta}{\gamma}+a)$ is false.

Indeed, $\frac{\beta}{\gamma}$ has degree at most $4$ since $\left(\frac{\beta}{\gamma}\right)^4=-2$.
But $\beta+\gamma$ has degree $8$.

Therefore, $\mathbb{Q}(\beta +a\gamma)=\mathbb{Q}(\frac{\beta}{\gamma}+a)$ is false for $a=1$.

Comment: $\mathbb{Q}(\beta,\gamma) = \mathbb{Q}(\beta, i)$ has degree $8$.

Comment: @Slade, thanks!